# Highcharts / Highstock datetime null data connected even with connectNulls: false

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get a stacked area highstock chart not to display null values. Here are the options:

```
var chartOpts = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: "graphContainer",
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         ordinal: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    legend: {enabled: true},
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            connectNulls: false,
            stacking: 'normal',
            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#666666'
            }
        }
    },
    series: []
};
```

This is the code for data filling:

```
$.post('GetData',{fechaInicio:fechaInicio, fechaFin:fechaFin},function(dataXML) { 
           var xml = $(dataXML);
           var fecha;
           var hora;
           var fechaUTC;
           var dato;
           var division;
           xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {
               var seriesOptions = {
                   name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                   data: []
               };
                // push data points
               $(series).find('data point').each(function(i, point) {
                   division=$(point).text().split(",");
                   fecha = division[0].split("/");
                   hora = division[1].split(":");
                   fechaUTC = Date.UTC(parseInt(fecha[2]),(parseInt(fecha[0])-1),parseInt(fecha[1]),parseInt(hora[0]),parseInt(hora[1]));
                   dato = parseInt(division[2]);
                   seriesOptions.data.push([fechaUTC, dato]);
               });
                chartOpts.series.push(seriesOptions);
           });
           var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOpts);
      });
```

What I get from this is (sorry for the links but I can not post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFt6R.jpg

Disabling all data series except SOVQ, I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak44n.jpg

In the last chart it seems that the data is constant from the first hour (00:00) to 14:15, but in that interval there is null data, so what I expect is that interval empty.

If you can see the options code I have the connectNulls option set as false (I think false value is the default for highstock). Does anybody know if there is some other option to not displaying null data?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Are you sure you really have null data points? From a quick glance at your code, I don't see any way for dato to be null. I'd set a breakpoint on this line:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOpts);
```

And make sure that there really are data points with null. I suspect there aren't.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for replying. OK, there are no data points with null values indeed, maybe I am trying to do something that is not possible. The values I get are interval points of 15 min, but there could be the case that in a longer interval there are no data, for exemple: (00:00,125 00:15,257 00:30,365 00:45,214 01:00,201 14:30,40 14:45,110) So, in the interval between 01:00 and 14:30, there is no data, and I expected to see that interval empty, but now with your comment I can realize that I should code something else to generate those intervals with null values... Thanks again...

Comment: The problem with null values is that it indicators, example like the SMA don't handle it well and treat it as a 0...my end goal is just to be able to at a glance see 'missing data'